# MKAnnotations Not Showing Up On Map iOS 9 / Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, json, mkmapview, swift2, mkannotation

Trying to show 100 EV charger stations on map using annotations that display their name and address, but only one of the 100 annotations which should be displayed by below code is showing up on the map.

Code builds fine and does not have any error flags, but I have a feeling I am doing something wrong with the map annotation code. During runtime get a long error message in debugger which begins:

> 2015-11-05 01:07:47.758 JSON[65210:8214517] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
>    Stack:(
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd67f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fdc2deb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd67e7d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
>       3   Foundation                          0x000000010e35c289 _AssertAutolayoutOnMainThreadOnly + 79
>       4   Foundation                          0x000000010e1bccce -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 31
>       5   UIKit                               0x000000010e95ed4a -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 575
>       6   UIKit                               0x000000010e96c7e7 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1967
>       7   MapKit                              0x000000010e6f2c90 -[MKAnnotationContainerView addSubview:] + 128
>       8   MapKit                              0x000000010e6f283e -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotationView:allowAnimation:] + 466
>       9   MapKit                              0x000000010e5ff976 -[MKMapView addAnnotationRepresentation:allowAnimation:] + 487
>       10  MapKit                              0x000000010e66ed64 -[MKAnnotationManager _addRepresentationForAnnotation:] + 721
>       11  MapKit                              0x000000010e66e3be -[MKAnnotationManager updateVisibleAnnotations] + 1551
>       12  MapKit                              0x000000010e66f314 -[MKAnnotationManager observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 859
>       13  Foundation                          0x000000010e17b610 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 347
>       14  Foundation

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  JSON
//
//  Created by Matt Velker on 11/4/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 slingshot. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation](count: 100, repeatedValue: MKPointAnnotation())

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var mapLat:CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(40.596061)
    var mapLong:CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(-98.819799)
    var mapLongDelta:CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(50)
    var mapLatDelta:CLLocationDegrees = CLLocationDegrees(50)
    var mapCenterLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapLat, mapLong)
    var mapSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(mapLatDelta, mapLongDelta)
    var mapRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(mapCenterLocation, mapSpan)
    map.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://developer.nrel.gov/api/alt-fuel-stations/v1.json?fuel_type=ELEC&state=CA&limit=100&api_key=vo1v1jn4eZC83ni2pII19vYmzLmk7UQzID4VZsZT&format=JSON")!
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let urlContent = data {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlContent, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                //print(jsonResult)
                var lat: [CLLocationDegrees] = []
                var long: [CLLocationDegrees] = []
                var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
                var locations: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
                if let jsonArrayOfDictionaries = jsonResult["fuel_stations"] {
                    for var x=0; x < jsonArrayOfDictionaries!.count; x++ {
                        lat.append(jsonArrayOfDictionaries![x]["latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                        long.append(jsonArrayOfDictionaries![x]["longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
                        location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat[x], long[x])
                        locations.append(location)
                        self.annotations[x].coordinate = locations[x]
                        self.annotations[x].title = jsonArrayOfDictionaries![x]["station_name"] as? String
                        self.annotations[x].subtitle = jsonArrayOfDictionaries![x]["street_address"] as? String
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON serialization failed")
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
    map.addAnnotations(annotations)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread,...

```
...
self.annotations[x].coordinate = locations[x] //this line causes the error log
...
```

You should load the data in the background and then when you are done update the view in main thread.